# 2 vertical lines between a set of arrayed numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, algebraic-number-theory

This thing given below is what I want to know.
[image: I want to know what does this mean]

I want know what does this mean and how to calculate it if can. I also want the name for this array of numbers. If can please provide some links that can take me to study about this further. Because this is the problem I have got to solve. Thank you in advance and it would be really nice if you solve my problem.

Comment: Matrix ?........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is called a [matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)), and the bars denote the [determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) of the matrix.

They are a subject of study of [Linear Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra).

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand. I thought it couldn't be matrix because they were just vertical lines like | |. Since matrices normally use [ ] I misunderstood.